About Dvapara (the embodiment of Dvapara Yuga) outside Mahabharata
Those who read Mahabharata, we should know that Dvapara is an entity embodies Dwapara Yuga, once assisted Kali for Nala's downfall and also later incarnated as Shakhuni.
However, I want to know some more about him. So my question is, is there any other details for Dvapara apart from Nala-Damayanti event and his incarnation as Shakuni? Or Atleast, any scriptures indirectly mentioned or implied him?

I recently found that the Brahma Vaivarta Purana says that Dvapara is born from Goddess Saraswati:-

Sauti said, “Brahma, after the creation of the universe, implanted the seed in the beautiful Savitrl as a passionate person, implants the seed in his wife. Savitrl then held the seduce of Brahma in her womb for a hundred divine years and gave birth to channing Raginis. Thereafter six beautiful Ragas were created together with the rhythms Savitrl then gave birth of Satyayuga, Dvapara, Tretayuga and Kaliyuga.

Reference: Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Chapter 8
